# C# Sorting Objects By A Value

Tags: c#, sorting, sortedlist, icomparable, sorteddictionary

I want to hold a list of **CollidableActor** objects, sorted by their property "*.Position.X*".

I am wondering on what would be the quickest (most efficient) method of doing this. At first I was thinking of using a SortedDictionary, and then a SortedList, but I read that SortedDictionaries are faster anyway.

Now I'm confused, because I don't know whether I want a dictionary or list. Also, when implementing the **IComparable** interface, and creating my *CompareTo()* method, would it be ample enough just to return *.Position.X*?

If not, is there a better structure or class that I could use that would sort things quickly as I add/remove them, according to *.Position.X*? (I will be adding/removing objects from the list a lot; would it be better to sort as the objects are added, or once an update, before I use the list?).

Thank you.

Edit: Infact, as all the objects will be unique, would some sort of HashSet collection be advisable? Thanks.

Comment: How many objects are likely to be in your list, requiring sorting?  Tens, hundreds, millions?

Comment: Upper hundreds; i.e. between 100 and 1000.

Comment: I see, in that case it's likely any performance improvement would be small on a modern client (that said you know your setup better than me :))

For my money I'd implement IComparable to return .Position.X and just use a sorted list for simplicity - exactly as you propose.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this by **modelling the problem domain** in the solution. Think about your domain, is it a canvass/grid on which you want to render your collidable objects, are you tring to solve a scheduling problem? Based on that design your data structure.

Lets list down the goals for our data structure -

1. We should be able to insert objects quickly.
2. We should be able to access objects by Position.X efficiently.
3. We should be able to get Position of an Object by its Id efficiently.

**Create your own data structure** which meets these goals by encapsulating a sorted list and a hashtable in your own class -

public class MyCanvas
{
    private IDictionary _positionMap = new SortedList();
    private IDictionary _objectMap = new HashTable();

```
public void Add(MyObject obj)
{
     _positionMap.Add(obj.Location.X, obj);
     _objectMap.Add(obj.Id, obj);
}

public MyObject GetPositionById(string id)
{
     return _objectMap[id].Location.X;
}

public IEnumerable<MyObject> SortedByX()
{
     _positionMap.GetEnumerator();
}

public void Delete(string id)
{
     var obj = _objectMap[id];
     _locationMap.Remove(obj.Location.X);
     _objectMap.Remove(id);
}
```

}

Note - please note that the code may not compile and concerns like error handling, threading issues etc needs to be taken care of.